# Java - Generic types and collections

Tags: java, collections, generic-collections

I'm trying to learn about the use of generic types and I've noticed something weird when I was experimenting with some lines of code.

The first piece of code is inside a class named "A":

```
public void func(int k, List list) {
    list.add(9);
    list.add(true);
    list.add("a string");
    }
```

The second piece of code is in a different class, inside the main function:

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arr.add(14);
        System.out.println(arr.toString());
        a.func(8, arr);
        System.out.println(arr.toString());
```

Running the code results in this lines being printed:

> [14]
>
> [14, 9, true, a string]

This got me pretty confused since `arr` is an `ArrayList` of type `Integer`, how can it contain objects of type `boolean` and `String`? Is there a transformation of the list in the function `func` to a raw type (which mean it becomes of generic type `Object`)? And if so how is it possible since you cannot do this for example: `List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Object>();`?

Would love some clarification on this, maybe it will help me grasp this subject of generic types better. Thanks!

Comment: You should read about [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and also [heap pollution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not allow the creation of generic Arrays. The Java Collection Classes are mainly implemented using `Object` arrays. The ArrayList class may look like the following

```
public class ArrayList<T> implements List<T>, Serializable {
    private transient Object[] data;
    // more content...
}
```

When creating a new Instance of the `ArrayList` a new `Object[]` array is created that can hold objects of any type. Typesafety is only achieved through using the generic Type Parameter.

Since List did not provide any Type parameter it makes use of the `rawtype` and anything can be added to the list. Therefore always make sure to infer template arguments to keep the typesafety.

```
public void func(int k, List<Integer> list) {
    list.add(9);      // works
    list.add(true);   // compile error
    list.add("a string");  // compile error
}
```

You should never use `rawtypes`. Depending on your compiler settings warnings will be omitted. 
It's better to use (bound/unbound) wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

Reason behind such kind of output is that you are passing `List` as an parameter to `func( int k , List list ) .`
And **list** in **func** method is non- generic which allows you to add string as well so you are getting such output.

```
 List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                arr.add(14);
                System.out.println(arr.toString());
                a.func(8, arr); // here you are passing a list 
                System.out.println(arr.toString());

    public void func(List list) { // here List in non-generic 
        list.add(9);
        list.add(true);
        list.add("a string");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a Generic code in Java is to provide type-safety before the actual code compilation. The compiled code have no type, that's why we don't face any problem in our code becuase when actually `func()` method is called, the `List arr` doesn't have any type.

When we're calling `System.out.println(arr.toString())`, we're just printing an object. This will fine on any type (i.e., int, boolean, String etc...). That's why we don't encounter any exception.

However, just try to assign a value from this list and we'll get `java.lang.ClassCastException`

```
...
func(8, arr);
System.out.println(arr.toString());
int a = arr.get(2);
```